# Batch Apex - Structure of shared lists

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to decide if I should move my lists of dates from the EXECUTE to the START or top of the class. Right now I believe that my lists of dates are being rebuilt each time the EXECUTE loop is run which is not needed as the list of dates never changes. Can someone help me out? I have deleted most of the code to make it easier to see and just added some comments for guidance on what is going on.

```
    global class batch_AccountServicing implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

        // instance member to retain state across transactions
        //Hope to use this value in email after batch finishes. 
        global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;


        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
            return Database.getQueryLocator(
                'SELECT Id,Name FROM ...'
            );
        }

        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account_Servicing_Task__c> scope){

            List<Date>      allDays         = new list<Date>(); //Business days
            List<Date>      Mondays         = new list<Date>(); //All Mondays
            List<Date>      Tuesdays        = new list<Date>(); //All Tuesdays
            List<Date>      Wednesdays      = new list<Date>(); //All Wednesdays
            List<Date>      Thursdays       = new list<Date>(); //All Thursdays
            List<Date>      Fridays         = new list<Date>(); //All Fridays
            List<Date>      Weekdays        = new list<Date>(); //All weekdays in the month
            List<Date>      Weekends        = new list<Date>(); //All weekends in the month        


//Find and populate the lists with dates. 


            For(Account_Servicing_Task__c tsk:Scope){  
               //Do work on each record from 
            }


            Insert accActivities;

        }    
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            //Send Email upon completion 
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to put it in the start block, I would populate this sort of data in the constructor.

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements ...
{
    public MyBatch()
    {
        // set up state here
    }
    // remainder of implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I was able to move my date logic to the constructor. I moved my list and variable creation before the constructor and created them as "Public FINAL" variables as the values don't change.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this population in the class's constructor (which you'd need to create) and declare these values as instance variables.

Since you're already implementing `Database.Stateful`, you'll preserve class storage across batch invocations. Since you're populating them anyway, it won't cost you any heap and will save however much CPU time it takes to process your lists.